# L293D Logic Current leak

Tags: arduino, motor, l293d

I connected my arduino to L293d and then to a small water pump. I noticed that even when motor power suppply was off,  the motor was running at low speed possibly drawing current from Arduino pins. 
When the IN pins are both pulled low or high, there is no current so technically it is working as per my requirement but I am worried whether it is bad for my arduino board by drawing power away.
I referred the following article. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=179186 but couldn't draw any conclusion. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** Vcc pins:

- **Vcc1** is meant for the logic supply
- **Vcc2** is meant for the motor supply

Data sheet cautions that **Vcc2 >= Vcc1**, so shutting off the motor's supply doesn't necessarily shut the motor down completely...it might still get some drive from **Vcc1**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @glen_geek. Do you think that it is bad for the arduino board? . I am just starting out with electronics and this is helpful. So all I have to do is to ensure a Vcc2 supply greater than Vcc1. Great!.

Comment: Not bad for the microcontroller chip on the arduino board. But there is a voltage regulator somewhere that supplies +5V to your arduino, through which extra motor current flows that would otherwise be supplied from Vcc2. That extra current would cause the regulator chip to run hotter.